# Rails: use image for a column in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, model, upload

I want users to be able to upload an image and have it be associated with a particular model. When I create my migration, what type do I use for my column? In the view I would like it to look something like this:

```
<%= form_for @person, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :picture %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks guys :)

Comment: If you want the picture to be readily available, i.e. it will be shown on pages of your site, then you should not store it in the database.  There are good suggestions below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably `:binary` -- but, have you considered using something like [Paperclip](http://rubygems.org/gems/paperclip) to handle image uploads for you? It can get really complicated otherwise.

Comment: Can you explain why it becomes more complicated? The pictures I want to use are about 20kb

Comment: If you don't mind handling the validations (to ensure bad things aren't uploaded) and dealing with storing binary data in a database (as opposed to the server or a cloud storage system), you can do it. But gems like Paperclip will give you everything you need for a lot less work.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the usage of an external plugin such as [Paperclip](http://railscasts.com/episodes/134-paperclip) or [Carrierwave](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads).

Comment: +1 for using a gem for uploads. You don't want to reinvent the wheel. there's an excellent railscast on carrierwave which I'd highly recommend. http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Comment: @Benjamin: Because it's easier than inventing everything yourself. Both plugins have excellent support for scaling to multiple versions and storing in a variety of backends (local filesystem, Amazon S3, MongoDB GridFS, you name it) instead of in the database. Storing files in a relational database using BLOBs is often not the best option for storing a large number of (large) files).

Answer (score 1):

There's also the [`AWS-3 gem`](http://amazon.rubyforge.org/), if you just want cloud storage. I would think performance alone would be enough to not store an image in a DB.

Comment: On closer look, that gem might not be updated for Rails 3 -- though a fork might.